# How to convert from string array to int array and then sort it using c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I have string array initialized like that:

```
char ** strArray;

if ( (strArray = malloc(sizeof(*strArray) + 3)) == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ls1: couldn't allocate memory");
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
strArray[0] = NULL;

strArray[0] = "111";
strArray[1] = "222";
strArray[2] = "1";
strArray[3] = "2";
```

I want to convert this string array to int array, like that:

```
int * toIntArray(char ** strArray) {

int size = getCharArraySize(strArray);
int intArray[size];
int i;

for ( i = 0; i < size  ; ++i)
{
   intArray[i] = atoi(strArray[i]);
   printf( "r[%d] = %d\n", i, intArray[i]);

} 
intArray[size] = '\0';
return intArray;
```

}

```
int getCharArraySize(char ** strArray) {
  int s = 0;
  while ( strArray[s]) {
        printf("Char array: %s.\n", strArray[s]);
    s++;
 }
 return s;
}
```

And then I want to sort this int array.

I must have string array initilized like above (char ** strArray) and then convert this to int array and then sort it. Can anybody help my with that? I would ask about printed sorted integer in main function.

Comment: I want to add that code above maybe does not work correctly.

Comment: should be `strArray = malloc(sizeof(*strArray) * 5)` and `strArray[4] = NULL;`

Comment: and `intArray[size] = '\0'; return intArray;` both wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few minor things to take note of in the question code:

```
char ** strArray;

if ( (strArray = malloc(sizeof(*strArray) + 3)) == NULL ) {
    fprintf(stderr, "ls1: couldn't allocate memory");
    //exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

If successful, the intention of the above code allocates memory to strArray sufficient for three `char *`'s.  Specifically, strArray[0], strArray[1](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23876772_how-to-convert-from-string-array-to-int-array-and-then-sort-it-using-c.c) and strArray[2].

**NOTE:** *As pointed out in Matt McNabb's comment below, it actually incorrectly allocates memory sufficient for one char *, and three extra bytes.*

```
strArray[0] = NULL;
```

The above line sets sets the first pointer in the **strArray to point at NULL.

```
strArray[0] = "111";
```

The above code is odd.  After just setting strArray[0] to point at NULL, the above line changes it to point to "111".  Kind of makes setting it to NULL (in the first place) seem unnecessary.

```
strArray[1] = "222";
strArray[2] = "1";
```

The above two lines initialize the other two pointers in the strArray correctly.

```
strArray[3] = "2";
```

The above line attempts to initialize strArray[3], when that element of the array really doesn't exist.  So, it is changing something to point to "2", but probably not with the expected result.

Perhaps the intent would be better served by changing the above code to:

```
   char **strArray;
   size_t strArrayElements=4;

   if(NULL == (strArray = malloc((strArrayElements+1) * sizeof(*strArray))))
      {
      fprintf(stderr, "ls1: couldn't allocate memory");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

   strArray[strArrayElements] = NULL;

   strArray[0] = "111";
   strArray[1] = "222";
   strArray[2] = "1";
   strArray[3] = "2";
```

As can be observed, the above code allocates 5 elements (strArrayElements+1) to the **strArray.  The last element `strArray[4]` is initialized to NULL; a marker to indicate `End-Of-List`.  Then the other 4 elements [0..3] are initialized.

---

Now shifting focus to:

```
int * toIntArray(char ** strArray) {
   int size = getCharArraySize(strArray);
   int intArray[size];
   int i;

   for ( i = 0; i < size  ; ++i)
      {
         intArray[i] = atoi(strArray[i]);
         printf( "r[%d] = %d\n", i, intArray[i]);
      } 
   intArray[size] = '\0';
   return intArray;
}
```

The above code is successful at converting the strings to their integer forms, and storing them in `intArray`.  However, the code is flawed when it attempts to `return intArray` to the caller.  The `intArray` variable was declared as a local stack object.  The `return` statement causes all such stack variables to become invalid; and allows the stack memory such variables were using to be used for other things.

Perhaps the the following code better represents what was intended.  It allocates memory from the heap for intArray.  This allocated memory can outlive the return statement:

```
int *toIntArray(char **strArray)
   {
   int size = getCharArraySize(strArray);
   int *intArray = malloc(size * sizeof(*intArray));
   int i;

   for ( i = 0; i < size  ; ++i)
      {
      intArray[i] = atoi(strArray[i]);
      printf( "r[%d] = %d\n", i, intArray[i]);
      }

   intArray[size] = '\0';
   return(intArray);
   }
```

---

Spoiler code may be found **[here](http://www.mahonri.info/SO/23876772_how-to-convert-from-string-array-to-int-array-and-then-sort-it-using-c.c)**.

Comment: "If successful, the above code allocates memory to strArray sufficient for three `char *`s" - no, it allocates memory sufficient for one `char *`, and three extra bytes.

Comment: Mahonri, thank you for fast reply. It was very helpful.

Comment: @MattMcNabb, very correct.  I have addressed this in the answer.  Thanks for pointing that out.